# jQuery Autocomplete not filtering but showing results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm just trying something out, as an experiment, with the jQuery autocomplete widget.

I used this as an example:
[Autocomplete | Custom Data](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

But when i try it, it's not filtering the results.
it only shows all results when i type something and then 'backspace-it-all'

here's my code:

```
    <script>

    var projects = <?
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSQLJSON)){
        $resultS = unserialize(base64_decode($row['safe']));
        $resultS['login']  = $row['login'];
        $resultS['shop']   = $row['shop'];
        $resultS['sqlext'] = $row['sql_ext'];
        array_push($resultB,$resultS);
    }
  echo json_encode($resultB);
    ?>;
 $(function() {
    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: projects,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.shop );
        $( "#project-description" ).html( "<b>DB Name:</b> "+ui.item.db_name +"<br><b>DB IP:</b> "+ui.item.db_ip+"<br><b>DB Login:</b> "+ui.item.db_login+"<br><b>DB Pass:</b> "+ui.item.db_pass+"<br><b>Login:</b> "+ui.item.login );
        return false;
      }
    })
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.shop + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="project">
<input type="hidden" id="project-id">
<p id="project-description"></p>


</body>
```

The PHP while returns a valid json format as a variable.

Everything works, when i select a result, i get the details and stuff, only the filtering doesn't work.

Can't seem to pinpoint the problem?
Any Ideas?

Thx, Bert

EDIT:
json data (edit the data for security ;) )
login has special characters like '

> Dtj6V+RsYD*to

' and pass also?

```
 [
    {
        "db_ip": "XXXX",
        "db_name": "XXXX",
        "db_login": "XXXX",
        "db_port": "XXXX",
        "db_pass": "XXXX",
        "login": "XXXX",
        "shop": "XXXX",
        "sqlext": "XXXX"
    },
    {
        "db_ip": "XXXX",
        "db_name": "XXXX",
        "db_login": "XXXX",
        "db_port": "XXXX",
        "db_pass": "XXXX",
        "login": "XXXX",
        "shop": "XXXX",
        "sqlext": "XXXX"
    },
    {
        "db_ip": "XXXX",
        "db_name": "XXXX",
        "db_login": "XXXX",
        "db_port": "XXXX",
        "db_pass": "XXXX",
        "login": "XXXX",
        "shop": "XXXX",
        "sqlext": "XXXX"
    }
]
```

Also tried with only 'shop' in the json data, because i thought it could be something with the special characters or so, but the same result.

Comment: Can you share the data you get in projects variable?

Comment: Added the json data as edit, it's JSONLint valid.

Comment: The jqueryUi autocomplete, source array should have values in one of the 2 below mentioned format:
An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

Comment: So you need to create a new array with label and value properties.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav! That did the trick, didn't know that these fields were necessary!